# Why is Focus Rectangle not shown until Tab key pressed?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms

I have a weird problem (probably only to understand) why in a test app the focus rect is not shown until i press the tab key.

I want to show a dialog with two radioboxes and two buttons. When i display the dialog, i'd like to see a focus rect around my first radiobutton. (So that the user can see where the focus is.) I ordered the controls and set the tabindex property from 0 to 4 so that they are in the correct order. (radiobox 1 has tabindex 0, ...)

When i show the dialog the first radiobox has the focus, but it has no focus rect around it. (Until i press tab key.)

I created an completely empty winforms project (Visual Studio 2010), added the controls and started it. So there is nothing special at all.

Can someone give me a hint what i am doing wrong?

Sorry, here is the code of my sample:

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, _
  e As System.EventArgs) _
    Handles Button1.Click

    Me.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As System.Object, _
  e As System.EventArgs) _
    Handles Button2.Click

    Me.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Shown(sender As Object, _
   e As System.EventArgs) _
  Handles Me.Shown

    RadioButton1.Focus()
    RadioButton1.Select()
    SendKeys.SendWait("{TAB}")
    SendKeys.SendWait("+{TAB}")

End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Ahem ... I forgot to say, that i am using Windows 7 (64 bit)

Comment: Tough bug to fix, nothing I tried worked.

Comment: I did a little (lot) more research and found out, that sending a "Tab" key to the form invokes the Control.ChangeUICues event in which the flag UICuesEventArgs.ShowFocus is set to true.
(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.changeuicues.aspx)
After this event is processed, the focus rect is visible. Does anybody know, how i can trigger/call this event directly? I didn't find any property which i can set this to true...

Comment: You can't / shouldn't really do that since it's a system setting.  On old XP, go to Control Panel - Display - Appearance - Effects, there is an option for "Hide underlined letters for keyboard navigation until I press the Alt key".  When unchecked, the radio button in the dialog appears as you want.  I don't know where that setting is in Win 7.  But basically, this is a user preference.

Comment: Good to know that this is a user setting. Thanks for saying it.

Comment: It's interesting that it is linked to that setting seeing that the text of the setting does not cover the focus rectangle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I commented, this is really a user preference setting.

But to show the rectangle, try inheriting your own RadioButton and override the `ShowFocusCues` function:

```
Public Class RadioWithFocus
  Inherits RadioButton

  Protected Overrides ReadOnly Property ShowFocusCues() As Boolean
    Get
      Return True
    End Get
  End Property

End Class
```

Answer (score 2):

For Win32/C++, send the WM_CHANGEUISTATE message to the parent window:

```
    // Enable focus rect and accelerator underline in all controls.
    ::SendMessage(WM_CHANGEUISTATE, MAKELONG(UIS_CLEAR, UISF_HIDEACCEL | UISF_HIDEFOCUS), 0);
```

Answer (score 2):

Martin Connel: your solution works for me! Thank you.

also in C#:

```cs
  using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
  ...
  [DllImport("USER32")]
  private static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int msg, int wp, int lp);
  private const int WM_CHANGEUISTATE = 0x0127; // from WinUser.h
  private const int UIS_CLEAR = 2;
  private const int UISF_HIDEFOCUS = 0x1;
  private const int UISF_HIDEACCEL = 0x2;

  ...

  SendMessage(Handle, WM_CHANGEUISTATE, UIS_CLEAR | ((UISF_HIDEACCEL | UISF_HIDEFOCUS) << 16), 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the inherited `Control.Focus()` in the initialization method of your form, or wherever applicable. Something like:

```
public Form1 () {
    //Other stuff here
    radiobox1.Focus();// If this is the name of your control
}
```

Another method to look at is [`Form.Activate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.activate.aspx). This is probably better to use in this context

Also, [`ActiveControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.containercontrol.activecontrol.aspx) might be helpful.

Comment: I knew the .Focus Method and tried it as first. Your .Activate Method was a good idea, but did the trick neither. :-/

Answer (score 0):

As LarsTech has said, this is a user setting.  For Windows 7, you can find this setting here:
Open Control Panel / Ease of Access Center / Make the Keyboard easier to use.

Look for a checkbox with the text "Underline keyboard shortcuts and access keys" and check it.

Rerun your app and you will see that the focus ques will now show up when your form first loads.

Enjoy