# How do I set a WinForms button focus so it looks like it was tabbed into it?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Tough to form a question out of this.  Here's some visuals from a very simple WinForms app.

Two buttons and I'm setting Focus() on button1 in Form_Shown.  Button1 does have focus, but you can hardly tell.

[image: Initial display on Form_Shown]

If I tab once to button2, notice it now has an additional rectangle to help show the button has focus.

[image: After hitting tab]

How do I get the button displayed with that same additional rectangle right from the get-go when the form is shown so the user can see it or other means to show the button has focus?

[image: Desired after Form_Shown]

I tried both Focus() and Select() on the button and I get the same result. Thanks!

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button1.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(64, 64, 64);
        button1.ForeColor = SystemColors.HighlightText;

        button2.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(64, 64, 64);
        button2.ForeColor = SystemColors.HighlightText;
    }

    private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button1.Focus();
        //button1.Select();
    }
```

**... UPDATE ...**
Based on initial comments/feedback, the focus-rectangle appears to be working as designed.  I guess what my problem is... I've used a dark color for the buttons (to match another product/app) and the initial Focus() on the button DOES put a border around it, but it is light in color and blends with the form.  If I drop the colors and leave the defaults, you can see the border and get a hint that it has focus... though still no focus-rectangle.

[image: Plain vanilla buttons]

So, I think I'll need to rethink this a bit.  I assume that border around the button that has Focus is not easily configurable via a property and I'd have to custom paint that?

Comment: It needs to be set as the default button for the form, so it responds to the enter key too.  I've done this with win32 dialogs but not winforms so someone else will need to answer how if that isn't a useful hint.  Also remember to remove the default state from whatever button had it before if the API call doesn't do that automatically.

Comment: I'm uncertain of a 'Default' for the form.  There are AcceptButton (Enter key) and CancelButton (Esc key) properties and those do not seem to make any difference in getting this to initially look as desired.  thx

Comment: Very closely related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14054036/show-hotkeys-at-all-times but you probably want `UISF_HIDEFOCUS` instead of `UISF_HIDEACCEL`

Comment: recommended reading: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050503-00/?p=35723

Comment: Note that there's a .NET wrapper for being told by the system whether to display keyboard cues: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.changeuicues?view=netframework-4.8.1#system-windows-forms-control-changeuicues and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.showfocuscues?view=netframework-4.8.1 -- but I don't think there's a wrapper for controlling them, so you'll have to p/invoke as in the linked answer

Comment: Override the Form's `OnLoad` method and pinvoke [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73982410/14171304).

Comment: Or the accepted answer if creating a custom `Button` is an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the first button is the "one and only" control with `TabIndex=0` so it gets the focus, but there shouldn't be a difference between this and being tabbed into.

If you choose to "custom paint that" you can make it minimally invasive by manually swapping out all `Button` for `ButtonEx` in designer.cs file. Then, with very little code, you can have a design-time property for the outer focus cue solid border as well as the dotted focus rectangle.

[image: design time properties]

[image: tab action]

---

```
class ButtonEx : Button
{
    public Color FocusRectangleColor
    {
        get => _focusRectangleColor;
        set
        {
            if (!Equals(_focusRectangleColor, value))
            {
                _focusRectangleColor = value;
                Refresh();
            }   
        }
    }
    Color _focusRectangleColor = Color.Red;

    public Color FocusCueColor
    {
        get => _focusCueColor;
        set
        {
            if (!Equals(_focusCueColor, value))
            {
                _focusCueColor = value;
                Refresh();
            }
        }
    }
    Color _focusCueColor = default;

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);
        if (Enabled && Focused && (MouseButtons == MouseButtons.None))
        {
            if (FocusRectangleColor != default)
            {
                using (Pen dottedPen = new Pen(FocusRectangleColor, 2f))
                {
                    dottedPen.DashStyle = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.DashStyle.Dot;
                    Rectangle focusRect = this.ClientRectangle;
                    focusRect.Inflate(-12, -12);
                    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(dottedPen, focusRect);
                }
            }
            if (FocusCueColor != default)
            {
                using (Pen cuePen = new Pen(FocusCueColor, FlatAppearance.BorderSize))
                {
                    Rectangle focusRect = this.ClientRectangle;
                    focusRect.Inflate(-2, -2);
                    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(cuePen, focusRect);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Testing**

The code as written should navigate correctly when:

- The **[Tab]** key is used to navigate.
- The mouse is used to click the button.
- `button.Focus()` is called programmatically.
- `SelectNextControl()` is called from the currently focused control.
- `ActiveControl` is set programmatically.

---

In order to behave:

- The `TabOrder` of the controls needs to be set correctly
- The `TabStop` property should be `true` for controls you want to tab otherwise false.
- The Form must be active.
- The button that should have focus must have the lowest tab index.

**Testbench**

Here's the code I used to test this answer with with the values for `TabIndex` as shown in VS Menu\View\Tab Order. [Clone](https://github.com/IVSoftware/button-renderer.git). Using the combo box, timer modes can be selected to cycle though the three "programmatic" options of navigation from the list above.

[image: tab order]

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    enum TimerMode { None, FocusNext, SelectNext, NextActive }
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        comboBoxTimers.Items.AddRange(Enum.GetValues(typeof(TimerMode)).OfType<object>().ToArray());
        comboBoxTimers.SelectedIndex = 0;
        comboBoxTimers.SelectionChangeCommitted += async(sender, e) =>
        {
            _timerMode = TimerMode.None;
            await _busy.WaitAsync();
            _timerMode = (TimerMode)(comboBoxTimers.SelectedItem ?? TimerMode.None);
            BeginInvoke(()=>ActiveControl = button1);
            string name;
            switch (_timerMode)
            {
                case TimerMode.FocusNext:
                    do
                    {
                        await Task.Delay(1000);
                        if (!comboBoxTimers.DroppedDown)
                        {
                            name = ActiveControl?.Name ?? string.Empty;
                            switch (name)
                            {
                                case nameof(button1): button2.Focus(); break;
                                case nameof(button2): button3.Focus(); break;
                                default: case nameof(button3): button1.Focus(); break;
                            }
                        }
                    } while (_timerMode == TimerMode.FocusNext);
                    _busy.Release();
                    break;
                case TimerMode.SelectNext:
                    do
                    {
                        await Task.Delay(1000);
                        if (!comboBoxTimers.DroppedDown)
                        {
                            if (ActiveControl != null) SelectNextControl(
                                ctl: ActiveControl,
                                forward: true,
                                tabStopOnly: true,
                                nested: true,
                                wrap: true
                            );
                        }
                    } while (_timerMode == TimerMode.SelectNext);
                    _busy.Release();
                    break;
                case TimerMode.NextActive:
                    do
                    {
                        await Task.Delay(1000);
                        if (!comboBoxTimers.DroppedDown)
                        {
                            name = ActiveControl?.Name ?? string.Empty;
                            switch (name)
                            {
                                case nameof(button1): ActiveControl = button2; break;
                                case nameof(button2): ActiveControl = button3; break;
                                default: case nameof(button3): ActiveControl = button1; break;
                            }
                        }
                    } while (_timerMode == TimerMode.NextActive);
                    _busy.Release();
                    break;
            }
        };
    }
    TimerMode _timerMode = TimerMode.None;
    SemaphoreSlim _busy = new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1);
}
```

Comment: Since your suggestion is to create a custom Control, it could be useful to let know that the default behavior that generates Keyboard Cues (as when pressing TAB) is determined by the `ShowFocusCues` Property. So, if you override the Property to return `true` when the Control has focus, i.e., `protected override bool ShowFocusCues => Focused;`, you have the same effect as pressing TAB when the Control is selected with the Mouse (or is set as the `ActiveControl`)

Comment: @Jimi I know you're usually on point with these things, but what is the added benefit of doing that when the default focus scheme works so well? And where the OP left the question was: _"I guess what my problem is... I've used a dark color for the buttons (to match another product/app) and the initial Focus() on the button DOES put a border around it, but it is light in color and blends with the form._" so I'm trying to solve the _contrast_ problem mainly because OP says the focus is correct but hard to see.

Comment: My comment is related to what the OP is asking: *If I tab once to button2 [...] How do I get the button displayed with that same additional rectangle [...]*. Setting `ShowFocusCues = true` when the Button has focus, doesn't affect the border (if the OP sets `FlatStyle = Flat` and the border is set to `0`, there's no border at all), it affects the inner focus rectangle that is drawn around the text. The color selected for the focus rectangle is calculated internally, so it contrasts with the background, maintaining the general look and feel -- Also note: *it could be useful to let know*

Comment: Thx, I see now. Under the heading _how do I get the button displayed with that same additional rectangle_, OP shows a graphic with the red arrow pointing to the dotted focus rectangle. This had me "not consider" the rectangle surrounding the button. I've made the appropriate adjustments.

Comment: @Jimi and IV. - Yeah, my question should have allowed a bit more flexibility as I was ultimately trying to make it more obvious to the user that the but had focus.  The focus-rectangle and changing the border color are both helpful.  Thanks for your time.

Answer (score -2):

If you have only two buttons you can press Tab key two times (or if you have
more you can do by length)

Here's the code sample:

```
private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SendKeys.Send("{TAB}");
        SendKeys.Send("{TAB}");
    }
```

Comment: I feel like there should be a better way to get there instead of sending keystrokes.  I have several forms with several controls, however... I just tried and I could do Tab and then Left-Arrow to go back to the first button.  It seems silly... though I am open to this if nothing else is more savvy.

Comment: This is not a production-ready solution, since it's very fragile.  If another application is receiving keyboard input at the moment this code runs, the TAB presses will end up in that other program, causing unexpected mayhem.

Comment: This is terrible advice and should be disregarded entirely